# Overriding style of links in nested div

Tags: html, css, class, hyperlink, colors

I have a problem setting the color of links in nested div. The links appear with default styling of links in parent div element.

In a nutshell, let's say we have following HTML-code:

```
<body>
    <div id="message">
        <div class="wrap">
            <a href="...">Link 1</a>
            <a href="...">Link 2</a>
            <div class="website">
                <div class="website-button">
                    <a href="...">Link 3</a>
                    <a href="...">Link 4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

To style the `Link 1` and `Link 2` elements within `#message/wrap` containers I use:

```
        #message a:link { color: rgba(85, 165, 255, 1.0); }
        #message a:visited { color: rgba(85, 165, 255, 1.0); }
        #message a:hover { color: rgba(95, 185, 255, 1.0); }
        #message a:active { color: rgba(95, 185, 255, 1.0); }
```

Also, I need the `Link 3` and `Link 4` links to be of a white color. I am styling these links this way:

```
        .website-button a:link,
        .website-button a:visited,
        .website-button a:hover,
        .website-button a:active {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
```

The problem is I can't override the style of links within `.website-button` element. They stay blue no matter what I do.

Below is the excerpt from my page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
            a { text-decoration: none; }
            a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
            .wrap {
                max-width: 800px;
                margin: 32px auto;
                padding: 0 24px;
            }
            #message {
                overflow: hidden;
                background: rgba(62, 72, 119, 1.0);
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
            }
            #message a:link { color: rgba(85, 165, 255, 1.0); }
            #message a:visited { color: rgba(85, 165, 255, 1.0); }
            #message a:hover { color: rgba(95, 185, 255, 1.0); }
            #message a:active { color: rgba(95, 185, 255, 1.0); }
            .website {
                width: 100%; height: auto;
                margin: 0.6rem 0 1.6rem 0;
            }
            .website-button {
                width: 50%;
                height: auto;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 12px 18px;
                background: #f50;
                font-size: 1.8rem;
                line-height: 2.0rem;
                text-transform: none;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: 700;
            }
            .website-button a:link,
            .website-button a:visited,
            .website-button a:hover,
            .website-button a:active {
                color: #ffffff;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="message">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Hello!</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <h3>Twitter: <a href="https://twitter.com/zimnovich">ZimNovich</a></h3>
        <div class="website">
        <div class="website-button"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/zimnovich/mobirrel-radio-edit">Listen it on SoundCloud</a></div>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <h3>Instagram: <a href="https://instagram.com/zimnovich">ZimNovich</a></h3>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evrgay

Comment: is `!important` not working?

Comment: @Siraj, yes, it is working, thanks!

Comment: is that means my answer should be marked as accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your selectors starting with `#message` have a higher priority than the selectors that start with `.website-button`

Why is that? Well, each selector is given a weight or a level of precedence. You see when you go 1 class then one 1 element for a selector you essentially have a score of (0,0,1,1). When you go 1 id and 1 element ( #message selectors) you have a score of (0,1,0,1).

The selector with the higher score is used.

If you were to change your `.website-button` selectors to start with you id `#message` that would give them a score of (0,1,1,1) and they would be used instead.

Here is a handy acronym to keep in your head when writing CSS selectors.

**ICE**

- *(i)* - inline style
- **I** - ID
- **C** - Class
- **E** - Element

Each id in your selector is worth (0,1,0,0), each class is worth (0,0,1,0), and each element is (0,0,0,1). Where each bucket has more precedence over the one before it.

> **Important to note:** 1 class is stronger than 10 elements, and 1 id is stronger than 10 classes

-> http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: Great answer, thank you! But what if I want to use `.website-button` class with divs that will be nested inside divs with other ids (other than `#message`)?

Comment: Then you still need a stronger selector. You'll need an ID higher up in your HTML that can help you. Try to keep in mind the score of your selectors, because as the system gets more complex it gets more challenging to beat strong rules. Use classes more than IDs so that your rules are inherently weaker and easier to beat.

Comment: I love the acronym, but the points part isn't correct. Any number of classes will always lose if another selector has more IDs.

Great answer other than that though!

Comment: Yeah, let's re-word the points part. Gotta be a simpler way to put it. Tried the 256 classes thing used a script to generate the classes: https://jsfiddle.net/ht9s4h6d/   ID still wins over 256 classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

    `#message .website-button a:link,
    #message .website-button a:visited,
    #message .website-button a:hover,
    #message .website-button a:active {
        color: #ffffff;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpJpQp

Try to add !important to the end of the following.  See attached code pen as well.

```
.website-button a:link,
        .website-button a:visited,
        .website-button a:hover,
        .website-button a:active {
            color: #ffffff !important;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap "website" class div as following

```
<div id="myWrap">
   <div class="website">
       <div class="website-button">
          <a href="...">Link 3</a>
          <a href="...">Link 4</a>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and use styles as this:

```
    #myWrapper a:link {
  color: rgba(85, 165, 255, 1.0);
}

#myWrapper a:visited {
  color: rgba(85, 165, 255, 1.0);
}

#myWrapper a:hover {
  color: rgba(95, 185, 255, 1.0);
}

#myWrapper a:active {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just mark the **css** of nested links as important.

```
   .website-button a:link,
   .website-button a:visited,
   .website-button a:hover,
   .website-button a:active {
       color: #ffffff !important;
   }
```